# Difference between Multidimensional Array notations (object[][] and object[,])

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I am wondering what is the difference between the two ways to define a Multidimensional Array in C#.

You can use `object[][]` and `object[,]` to work with multidimensional array.

Are there functional differences?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-is-differences-between-multidimensional-array-and-array-of-arrays-in-c

Comment: Possible duplicate _exactly_: http://stackoverflow.com/q/597720

Comment: @Jodrell My comment is also duplicate ironically :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `object[][]` is a notation for array of arrays. The second one `object[,]` is a two dimensional array.

The main difference is while the first one can contain different length "inner" arrays, the second one must be rectangular (e.g. 4x7).

Example:

```
int[][] a = new int[] { new int[]{ 1, 2 }, new int[]{ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }};
int[,] b = new int[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };
```

[This is an official tutorial.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: @MAfifi No, rectangular. It's possible to have 16 x 9 for example using `object[,]`