# multidimensional array of object c#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I use an array of array :

```
object[][] of =new object[lenght2][];
```

Now, what i want is to insert a new array into of[][], I try this :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < lenght2; i++)
  {
      Act = calcul_resporderbyact(responsable,v); // return array of object
      of[i] = Act;
 }
```

i want to know how to use some array from this multidimensional-array ??

Comment: start by saying what 'dont work' means, then what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: It should be `object[,] of =new object[lenght2,];`

Comment: @Anirudh `object[,] of =new object[lenght2,];` won't compile, you need to specify both lenghts like `object[,] of =new object[lenght1,lenght2];`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/11330990

Comment: Instead of creating of array of arrays You can try using List<object[]>.

Comment: @Naren - There may be a need for a fixed length

Comment: @Sayse That's right..But does it hamper the performance?

Comment: @Naren I don't know how its being used, for example, it could be used in a loop where the iterator is hardcoded (i.e `i < 5`)

Comment: @Sayse Thanks,I haven't thought of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have couple of mistakes, in your code `object[,] of =new object[lenght2][];`

`[,]` is not equal to `[][]`

you can try this:

```
object[][] of = new object[length2][];
of[i] = Act; //it means you can assign `new[] { new object() };`
```

Read this: [Multidimensional Array [][] vs [,]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567329/multidimensional-array-vs)

it says that `[,]` is multidimensional array and `[][]` is array of arrays. So for your use array of arrays is valid.

Answer (score 2):

In C# there are [jagged arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx) and [multidimensional arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx). In your example you seem to be mixing up the two.

Jagged arrays are created this way, and you'll have to construct each "sub-array" individually:

```
object[][] obj = new object[10][];
obj[0] = new object[10];
obj[1] = new object[10];
...
```

Multidimensional arrays on the other hand:

```
object[,] obj = new object[10,10];
```

Answer (score 1):

Multidimensional arrays (as opposed to jagged arrays) are always "rectangular", meaning that the length of each entry in the array is also fixed.

If you want just a list of arrays, which can have different lengths, then use `List<object[]>` as in

```
List<object[]> l = new List<object[]>();
l.Add(calcul_resporderbyact(responsable,v));
```

Or you could use a [jagged array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx):

```
object[][] l = new object[length2][];
l[i] = calcul_resporderbyact(responsable,v);
```